# Adding KML linestring intersection points to relevant linestring coordinates using QGIS

Tags: qgis, kml, linestring

I have a KML document with many LineStrings which I'm parsing and building a graph from in an application. Unfortunately not all LineStrings line up correctly (having the same vertex/coordinate), and I have to find the intersections and insert them in the correct place in both LineStrings' coordinates-array, as in the picture:

[image: Linestring intersections]

I've found all the intersection points by using `QGIS -> Vector -> Analysis Tools -> Line intersections`, but I'm stuck on the last step of inserting the intersection points into the two relevant LineStrings' coordinate-arrays, and I was hoping to be able to do this still in QGIS so that I can export it as a new KML document with the new points correctly included.